# How to preserve the current css class state of an element such as a div?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to learn and create a website in using asp.net mvc and I am now confused compared to using webforms. So,

I have 2 divs.

div1 contains an unordered list, which is used as the navigation strip

```
<ul id="navigation_list">
  <li id="navigation_items_1" class="navigation_items">@Html.ActionLink("ONE", "One")</li>
  <li id="navigation_items_2" class="navigation_items">@Html.ActionLink("TWO", "Two")</li>
  <li id="navigation_items_3" class="navigation_items">@Html.ActionLink("THREE", "Three")</li>
</ul>
```

div2 contains the would be contents depending on which navigation item in chosen in div one.

My question problem is- every time I click one of the navigation items, the entire page reloads therefore all my jquery manipulation of css properties of all navigation items are lost in Div1. Div 2 correctly changes its contents though.

How can I preserve the current css class state in div1 so that when I highlight a navigation item upon mouse clicking, the css property persists? I mean force that only div2 refreshes or something like that.

In controller, this is what I have:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(something.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /ie/One

    public ActionResult One()
    {
        return View(something.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /ie/Two

    public ActionResult Two()
    {
        return View(something.ToList());
    }
```

I also realize that the url changes every page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Html.ActionLink, you need Ajax.Actionlink http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink(v=vs.108).aspx

In one of the AjaxOptions arguments (UpdateTargetId) specify the div you wish to replace.

Also, make sure you are returning partial views into that div, or you will put an entire page's markup into it. It might help to change your ActionResults to PartialViewResults to help you remember what it's truly doing.

Here is an example for you:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("ONE", "One", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div2" })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to refresh div using Jquery you don't need ActionLink. Usy load() function. And change ActionResults in you controller to return PartialView() instead View().

So, in you View:

```
$(function () {
$('.one').click(function(){$('.firstcontent').load('/Home/One')}):
$('.two').click(function(){$('.secondcontent').load('/Home/two')}):
$('.three').click(function(){$('.thirdcontent').load('/Home/three')}):
});

<ul id="navigation_list">
  <li id="navigation_items_1" class="navigation_items"><a href="#" class="one">one</a></li>
  <li id="navigation_items_2" class="navigation_items"><a href="#" class="two">two</a></li>
  <li id="navigation_items_3" class="navigation_items"><a href="#" class="three">three</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="firstcontent"></div>
<div class="secondcontent"></div>
<div class="thirdcontent"></div>
```

And in your Controller:

```
public ActionResult One()
    {
        return PartialView(something.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /ie/Two

    public ActionResult Two()
    {
        return PartialView(something.ToList());
    }

     public ActionResult Three()
    {
        return PartialView(something.ToList());
    }
```